# SQL Error: ORA-38104: Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, sql-merge

```
MERGE /*+ GATHER_PLAN_STATISTICS*/
     INTO ATM_REQUEST ATM
    USING ATM_STATUS_VIEW ST
       ON (    ATM.accountno = ST.accountno
           AND atm.status IS NULL
           AND atm.remarks IS NULL)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
   UPDATE SET ATM.STATUS = ST.STATUS, ATM.REMARKS = ST.REMARKS;
```

am getting below error, can anyone help me on this.

```
Error at Command Line : 3 Column : 35
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-38104: Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated: "ATM"."STATUS"
```

Comment: You're using column `atm.status`in the `ON` clause, so it can't be changed the the `UPDATE`clause. You can move the `IS NULL` conditions into the `UPDATE` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using column `atm.status` in the `ON` clause, so it can't be changed the the `UPDATE` clause. You can move the `IS NULL` conditions into the `UPDATE` clause.

```
MERGE /*+ GATHER_PLAN_STATISTICS*/
     INTO atm_request atm
    USING atm_status_view st
       ON (atm.accountno = st.accountno)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
   UPDATE SET atm.status = st.status, atm.remarks = st.remarks
          WHERE     atm.status IS NULL
                AND atm.remarks IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

As it says, you can't update column(s) referenced in `ON` clause.

Perhaps you meant to do this:

```
MERGE /*+ GATHER_PLAN_STATISTICS*/
     INTO ATM_REQUEST ATM
    USING ATM_STATUS_VIEW ST
       ON (ATM.accountno = ST.accountno)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
   UPDATE SET ATM.STATUS = ST.STATUS, ATM.REMARKS = ST.REMARKS
          WHERE     atm.status IS NULL
                AND atm.remarks IS NULL
```